# Places which serve food

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a collective term for places which serve food? These include restaurants, cafes, food trucks, etc. Preferably a word which is commonly known.

Comment: Eateries? Food outlets?

Comment: @WS2 I think _eateries_ in particular is far more idiomatic than the accepted answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think one would be unlikely to hear anyone say - *let's look for a food establishment so we can eat*. It would appear to be a legal/bureaucratic term, employed in an official document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a *food establishment*.

Here's a definition from a [Minneapolis government site](http://www.minneapolismn.gov/health/inspections/food-definitions):

> A food establishment is an operation that:
>
> (1) stores, prepares, packages, serves, vends, or otherwise provides food for human consumption, including a restaurant, satellite or catered feeding location, market, grocery store, convenience store, special event food stand, school, boarding establishment, vending machine and vending location, institution, and retail bakery; or
>
> (2) relinquishes possession of food to a consumer directly or indirectly through a delivery service, including the home delivery of grocery orders or restaurant takeout orders, and a delivery service that is provided by common carriers.

It goes on to list and define various kinds of food establishments, including *restaurant* (which presumably includes cafes) and *mobile vendor*.